# How to place logo in right side of the navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav

Hi I am working on designing navigation bar. I want to keep application name in left side and logo in right side. Before to logo I want to keep one drop-down. I tried as below.

```css
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

    .navbar a {
        float: left;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .dropdown .dropbtn {
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        background-color: inherit;
        font-family: inherit;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      display: block; 
    }

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

    .dropdown-content a {
        float: none;
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
        }

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-brand {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: .3125rem;
    padding-bottom: .3125rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: inherit;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar" >
                <div class="navbar navbar-light" style="backgroundColor:#483D8B">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="fontSize:20px;color:#FFFFFF">Dashboard</a>

                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
                    
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="#">
                    <img alt="CompanyLogo" src={profilePageImage} />
                </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </body>
</html>
```

I am not able to design it in the way I want. Always project name, dropdown and logo comes one after the other but I want dropdown and logo in full right side. Can someone help me to figure it out. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what u r expecting:

Create a new div(right side content) and wrap the dropdown div and company logo into that div.
Then add flex and space-between property to the navbar div.

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.right-side-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.navbar-brand {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: .3125rem;
  padding-bottom: .3125rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-brand {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" </head>

  <body>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar navbar-light" style="backgroundColor:#483D8B">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="fontSize:20px;color:#FFFFFF">Dashboard</a>

        <div class="right-side-content">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
                    
                    </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="#">
            <img alt="CompanyLogo" src="https://dummyimage.com/40x40/fff/000?text=logo" />
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `float: left;` to `float: right;`

Comment: Hi Alex, If I do that along with project name it goes to right side. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `float: left;` to `float: right;` in the css class `.dropdown`;

```
.dropdown {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

2. Add `float: right;` in the css class `.navbar-light .navbar-brand`;

```
.navbar-light .navbar-brand {
    float: right;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
       .logo {
              display: none;
       }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
       <head>
              <meta charset="utf-8">
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
              <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
       </head>
       <body>
       <!-- Navigation -->
       <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">App Name</a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>

         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
           <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
             <li class="nav-item dropdown">
               <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 Dropdown
               </a>
               <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
               </div>
             </li>
           </ul>
                  <div class="logo" >
                         <img class="hidden-xs" src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
                  </div>
       </nav>

       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       </body>
</html>
```